# Trying to extract genre of movie using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning web scraping and was trying to extract the genre of the movie from the google search results.
I have provided the codes below.
I am proving the image with the part I want to extract highlighted [Part I want to extract is highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txdaB.png)

`<div class="wwUB2c PZPZlf" data-attrid="subtitle"><span data-ved="2ahUKEwizlJiu9OLoAhXFgeYKHXzvAlMQ2kooAjAlegQIJhAN">1999 ‧ Romance/Comedy ‧ 2h 4m</span></div>`

I want to extract the part "Romance/Comedy"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=1008&ei=uwqTXuyUB-Ov8QPIvbKACQ&q=notting+hill+&oq=notting+hill+&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzIHCAAQgwEQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIFCAAQgwEyBAgAEEM6BAgAEEdKDQgXEgkxMC0xOThnMThKCggYEgYxMC0xZzNQwN0XWMDdF2CW3xdoAHADeACAAasBiAGrAZIBAzAuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwis3vbz8uLoAhXjV3wKHcieDJAQ4dUDCAw&uact=5")


soup = bs(url.text, "lxml")

soup.select(".subtitle") #in this case it is returning a empty list
soup.find("div", {"class": "wwUB2c PZPZlf"}) #in this case also it is returning a empty list
soup.find("span", {"data-ved": "2ahUKEwizlJiu9OLoAhXFgeYKHXzvAlMQ2kooAjAlegQIJhAN"}) #in this case also it is returning a empty list
```

Comment: I think you need to use `requests`. You haven't actually fetched from the url using requests

Comment: even after adding ```request.``` i's the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of the classes look dynamic. You could try for a relationship between elements in DOM and tighten up with :contains on assumption that "‧" appears in text of interest and restricts to first node

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=1008&ei=uwqTXuyUB-Ov8QPIvbKACQ&q=notting+hill+&oq=notting+hill+&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzIHCAAQgwEQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIFCAAQgwEyBAgAEEM6BAgAEEdKDQgXEgkxMC0xOThnMThKCggYEgYxMC0xZzNQwN0XWMDdF2CW3xdoAHADeACAAasBiAGrAZIBAzAuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwis3vbz8uLoAhXjV3wKHcieDJAQ4dUDCAw&uact=5')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('span div[class]:contains("‧")').text.split('‧')[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
url = "https://www.google.com/search?biw=1920&bih=1008&ei=uwqTXuyUB-Ov8QPIvbKACQ&q=notting+hill+&oq=notting+hill+&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECCMQJzIHCAAQgwEQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIFCAAQgwEyBAgAEEM6BAgAEEdKDQgXEgkxMC0xOThnMThKCggYEgYxMC0xZzNQwN0XWMDdF2CW3xdoAHADeACAAasBiAGrAZIBAzAuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwis3vbz8uLoAhXjV3wKHcieDJAQ4dUDCAw&uact=5"
html = req.get(url)
#html = '''
#<div class="wwUB2c PZPZlf" data-attrid="subtitle">
#   <span data-ved="2ahUKEwizlJiu9OLoAhXFgeYKHXzvAlMQ2kooAjAlegQIJhAN">1999 ‧ Romance/Comedy ‧ 2h 4m</span>
#</div>
#'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
text = doc.getElement("div",attr="data-attrid",value="subtitle").text
print (text)
```

Result:

```
1999 ‧ Romance/Comedy ‧ 2h 4m
```

Comment: Thanks for replying,
By this how will I extract from the URL.

Comment: @YashPandey I changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, firstly, you need to make a request

**Wrong:**

```
soup = bs(url.text, "lxml")
```

**Correct:**

```
soup = bs(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")
```

Secondly, this data (Romance/Comedy) is downloaded by AJAX, so you can't get it from request to google search.

I'll update this answer if find how to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
But even after making request I am unable to do it.

Comment: Data is available in response.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser. `CSS` selector [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

You're looking for:

```py
soup.select_one('.wwUB2c span').text
# 1999 ‧ Romance/Rom-com ‧ 2h 4m
```

Also, you need to send a fake `user-agent` since default `user-agent` in `requests` library is [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) (*thus Google will know it's a bot and block a request*) so Google would treat your request as a "real" user visit, also known as [*`user-agent` spoofing*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent).

Pass `user-agent` in `headers`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

requests.get(YOUR_URL, headers=headers)
```

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Search-Knowledge-Graph-python-serpapi#bs4_result.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    "User-agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
    "Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  'q': 'nothing hill',  # query
  'hl': 'en',           # language
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

subtitle = soup.select_one('.wwUB2c span').text
print(subtitle)

# 1999 ‧ Romance/Rom-com ‧ 2h 4m
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Google Knowledge Graph API](https://serpapi.com/knowledge-graph) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that everything is already extracted and there's no need to digging inside HTML and find which selector to use. All that needs to be done is just to iterate over structured JSON and get what you were looking for.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "nothing hill",
    "hl": "en",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

subtitle = results['knowledge_graph']['type']
print(subtitle)

# 1999 ‧ Romance/Rom-com ‧ 2h 4m
```

P.S - I wrote a bit more detailed blog post about how to scrape [Google Knowledge Graph](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/how-to-scrape-google-knowledge-graph-with-python-2ilp).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi